# How to load related entities for each item in a collection using ABP framework?

Tags: c#, abp

I am working with the ABP framework and I have the following classes: A, B, and C. Class A has a collection of B objects, and each B object has a C object. Here is the code:

```cs
public class A 
{
    public ICollection<B> Bs {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
    public C c {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you configured the relationships (1-to-many, many-to-many) for your entities, you can override the `WithDetailsAsync` method of your repository implementation and include the collection as follows:

```cs
public override Task<IQueryable<A>> WithDetailsAsync()
{
   return base.WithDetailsAsync(x => x.Bs);
}
```

See the documentation for more info: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Best-Practices/Entity-Framework-Core-Integration#repository-implementation

---

Also, you can check [this article](https://community.abp.io/articles/many-to-many-relationship-with-abp-and-ef-core-g7rm2qut) and [this repository](https://github.com/EngincanV/ABP-Many-to-Many-Relationship) for an example.